# Using Python Regex to Simplify Latex Fractions

Tags: python, regex, math, latex, pdflatex

Sample code in Latex:

```
%Chebyshev of second kind
\begin{equation}
\sum_{\ell \hiderel{=} 0}^n\frac{( \ChebyU{\ell}@{x}  )^2}*{ \frac{\pi}{2}  }*=\frac{ 2^n  }{ \frac{\pi}{2}   2^n+1  }\frac{ \ChebyU{n+1}@{x}   \ChebyU{n}@{y}  - \ChebyU{n}@{x}   \ChebyU{n+1}@{y}  }{x-y}
\end{equation}
```

`\frac{(\ChebyU{\ell}@{x})^2}*{\frac{\pi}{2}}` is the fraction I am looking at for this specific case.  Since it is a fraction in the denominator of another fraction I would like to use Python regex to change this from `a/(b/c)` to `(ac)/b`.

Example output:

```
%Chebyshev of second kind
\begin{equation}
\sum_{\ell \hiderel{=} 0}^n\frac{(2 \ChebyU{\ell}@{x}  )^2}{\pi}*=\frac{ 2^n  }{ \frac{\pi}{2}   2^n+1  }\frac{ \ChebyU{n+1}@{x}   \ChebyU{n}@{y}  - \ChebyU{n}@{x}   \ChebyU{n+1}@{y}  }{x-y}
\end{equation}
```

End result: `\frac{(2\ChebyU{\ell}@{x})^2}{\pi}` is the fraction that the regex should result in.

How would I go about doing this with regex in Python?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a regex that should work. Note that I made a change in your LaTeX expression because I think there was an error (* sign).

```
astr = '\frac{(\ChebyU{\ell}@{x})^2}{\frac{\pi}{2}}'

import re
pat = re.compile('\\frac\{(.*?)\}\{\\frac\{(.*?)\}\{(.*?)\}\}')
match = pat.match(astr)
if match:
    expr = '\\frac{{{0}*{2}}}{{{1}}}'.format(*match.groups())
    print expr
```

NB: I did not include the spaces in your original expression.