# Regex: How to convert LaTeX fractions into an operable expression in Python?

Tags: python, regex, latex

I would like to create a parser that takes in any LaTeX formatted string and returns an expression that Python can evaluate.

I am having a couple of issues with fractions. Here are some example:

| LaTeX (input) | Interoperable String (output) |
| --- | --- |
| `\frac{1}{2}` | `((1)/(2))` |
| `\frac{x}{3b}` | `((x)/(3b))` |
| `\frac{2-m}{3}` | `((2-m)/(3))` |
| `\frac{7}{5+y}` | `((7)/(5+y))` |

Here is what I have tried so far:

```
fraction_re = re.compile(r"\\frac{(.*?)}{(.*?)}")

def parser(expression):

    fractions = fraction_re.findall(expression)

    for numerator, denominator in fractions:
        pattern = r"\\frac\{%s\}\{%s\}" % (numerator, denominator)
        replace = f"(({numerator})/({denominator}))"
        expression = re.sub(pattern=pattern, repl=replace, string=expression)

    return expression
```

This works fine for cases one and two (see table) but is having problems with cases three and four. I suspect that the `-` and the `+` symbols are causing issues as they themselves are regex metacharacters.

I thought of adding some extra lines to escape them, e.g.

```
numerator = re.sub(pattern='+', repl='\+', string=numerator)
```

But this doesn't strike me as a good long term strategy. I have also tried adding square brackets to the `pattern` variable (as normal regex symbols in square brackets are not interpreted as such), i.e.

```
pattern = r"\\frac\{[%s]\}\{[%s]\}" % (numerator, denominator)
```

But this didn't work either.

Can anyone help me?

Thanks in advance.

p.s.

I know that this has been asked many times on SO before (e.g. [Python Regex to Simplify LaTex Fractions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30873981/python-regex-to-simplify-latex-fractions;) [Using Python Regex to Simplify Latex Fractions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29355844/using-python-regex-to-simplify-latex-fractions;) [Using if-then-else conditionals with Python regex replacement](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44305870/using-if-then-else-conditionals-with-python-regex-replacement)) but I feel like their questions are a little different to mine and I have not been able to find an answer that helps me much.

Also I know that there already exist out-of-the-box parsers that do exactly what I'd want (for example: https://github.com/augustt198/latex2sympy) but I really would like to build this myself.

Comment: @Reti43 finding the fractions is not the issue. The issue the taking the matches and converting them into the format: `((numerator)/(denominator))`

Comment: I think your regex should be something along the lines of `{[^}]+}`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure why you're taking a two-stage approach; as you have noted it is causing you problems with regex meta characters in the second stage. You could just make the substitution as you match using `re.sub`:

```py
import re

fraction_re = re.compile(r'\\frac{([^}]+)}{([^}]+)}')

def parser(expression):
    return fraction_re.sub(r'((\1)/(\2))', expression)

print(parser(r'\frac{1}{2}  \frac{x}{3b}   \frac{2-m}{3}   \frac{7}{5+y}'))
```

Output

```
((1)/(2))  ((x)/(3b))   ((2-m)/(3))   ((7)/(5+y))
```

Note that it's more efficient to use `[^}]+` than `.*?` in your regex as it will reduce backtracking.

Comment: Wow this is so succinct! I knew that what I was doing was a little inefficent as my code was going over the string twice. So just to be clear does `\1` and `\2` mean group one and two?

Comment: @JacobStrauss exactly. You can use named groups as in Jan's answer, but I think this is easier.

Comment: Thanks Nick! I appreciate you for the time you've taken to help me out :)

Answer (score 1):

You could use a simple lambda function within `re.sub()` as in:

```
import re

data = r"""
some very cool \textbf{Latex} stuff

\begin{enumerate}
\item even a very cool item
\end{enumerate}

Here comes the fun
\frac{1}{2} 
\frac{x}{3b}
\frac{2-m}{3}
\frac{7}{5+y}
"""

rx = re.compile(r'\\frac\{(?P<numerator>[^{}]+)\}\{(?P<denominator>[^{}]+)\}')

data = rx.sub(lambda m: f"(({m.group('numerator')}/({m.group('denominator')})", data)
print(data)
```

Which will yield

```
some very cool \textbf{Latex} stuff

\begin{enumerate}
\item even a very cool item
\end{enumerate}

Here comes the fun
((1/(2)
((x/(3b)
((2-m/(3)
((7/(5+y)
```

---

The expression boils down to

```
\\frac\{(?P<numerator>[^{}]+)\}\{(?P<denominator>[^{}]+)\}
```

No need to use named groups, really, just to make it crystal clear.

Comment: Jan this is a superb answer, thanks for helping me out! I didn't think to use lambda functions, and named groups are new to me. I learnt loads, thanks